# How do I implement subscriptions in GraphQL HotChocolate?

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I am implementing [HotChocolate](https://hotchocolate.io/) as part of my ASP.NET API. I'm trying to add subscriptions to the chat portion on my app, however, the documentation on the HotChocolate site is not implemented yet. From what I can tell from other sites/frameworks, I can use the C# `IObservable<Chat>` as the return type for the subscription method.

Can anyone give me an example of a query method or point me towards another resource?

```
public async Task<IObservable<Message>> GetMessages(Guid chatId) {
  var messages = ..Get chats;

  return messages;
}
```

However, how does this work from a query standpoint? How do we trigger an event to update this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the original documentation link became obsolete I am posting this new link that refers to our workshop project.

Chapter 7 shows how to do subscriptions in two variants.
https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-workshop/blob/master/docs/7-subscriptions.md

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that documentation is perfect! Thanks for the speedy response as well!

Comment: https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-workshop/blob/master/docs/7-subscriptions.md